# Response.Write with an iframe

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, iframe

I have inherited an application that uses Cybersource as the credit card processing company.  It currently uses the CyberSource API and I am trying to convert it to use their hosted order page - specifically the silent order post method.  The example CyberSource gives to run it is as follows:

```
<form action="https://orderpagetest.ic3.com/hop/ProcessOrder.do" method="POST">
    <% insertSignature3("10", "USD", "sale"); %>
        <h2>Payment Information</h2>
        Card Type:      <select name="card_cardType"><br>
                            <option value="">
                            <option value="001">Visa
                            <option value="002">MasterCard
                            <option value="003">American Express
                        </select><br>
        Card Number:        <input type="text" name="card_accountNumber"><br>
        Expiration Month:   <input type="text" name="card_expirationMonth"> (mm)<br>
        Expiration Year:    <input type="text" name="card_expirationYear"> (yyyy)<br><br>

    <h2>Ready to Check Out!</h2>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">

</form>
```

The code for the insertSignature method is follows:

```
 public void insertSignature3( String amount, String currency, String orderPage_transactionType )
    {
        try
        {
            TimeSpan timeSpanTime = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime( 1970, 1, 1 );
            String[] arrayTime = timeSpanTime.TotalMilliseconds.ToString().Split( '.' );
            String time = arrayTime[0];
            String merchantID = GetMerchantID();
            if ( merchantID.Equals( "" ) )
                Response.Write( "<b>Error:</b> <br>The current security script (HOP.cs) doesn't contain your merchant information. Please login to the <a href='https://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc/hop/HOPSecurityLoad.do'>CyberSource Business Center</a> and generate one before proceeding further. Be sure to replace the existing HOP.cs with the newly generated HOP.cs.<br><br>" );
            String data = merchantID + amount + currency + time + orderPage_transactionType;
            String pub = GetSharedSecret();
            String serialNumber = GetSerialNumber();
            byte[] byteData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( data );
            byte[] byteKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( pub );
            HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1( byteKey );
            String publicDigest = Convert.ToBase64String( hmac.ComputeHash( byteData ) );
            publicDigest = publicDigest.Replace( "\n", "" );
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append( "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount\" value=\"" );
            sb.Append( amount );
            sb.Append( "\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"currency\" value=\"" );
            sb.Append( currency );
            sb.Append( "\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"orderPage_timestamp\" value=\"" );
            sb.Append( time );
            sb.Append( "\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"merchantID\" value=\"" );
            sb.Append( merchantID );
            sb.Append( "\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"orderPage_transactionType\" value=\"" );
            sb.Append( orderPage_transactionType );
            sb.Append( "\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"orderPage_signaturePublic\" value=\"" );
            sb.Append( publicDigest );
            sb.Append( "\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"orderPage_version\" value=\"4\">\n" );
            sb.Append( "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"orderPage_serialNumber\" value=\"" );
            sb.Append( serialNumber );
            sb.Append( "\">\n" );
            Response.Write( sb.ToString() );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Response.Write( e.StackTrace.ToString() );
        }
    }
```

Everything works when I run it in a test application.  However, I cannot use a form tag in my main application as the Master page has everything enclosed in a form tag and this would result in a nested form tag.  I have tried putting the form block in an iframe but cannot work out how to pass the additional information via the Response.Write call from the insertSignature(...) method.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this same issue.  We also went with an iframe approach.  On the page load (if postback) you will want to write out specific items in the Request (excluding the ViewState).  The example below shows writing out all items (except the ViewState).  This is wrapped in a ccInfo span that we can then get through JavaScript.

```
protected virtual void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Do any page binding, etc that needs to be done on intitial page load
    }
    else
    {
        //We came back from CyberSource ...

        //Will need to get from stored client hidden field ...
        string decision = Request.Form["decision"];

        if (verifyTransactionSignature(Request))
        {
            //Make sure we are only processing in the TEST environment if the particular setting
            //is set to test (Site_Settings.CYBERSOURCE_API_URL contains 'test' in it)
            string apiUrl = Settings.GetSetting(LocalConnectionString, "CYBERSOURCE_API_URL");
            //API isn't test, but CyberSource is (someone hacking?)
            if (!apiUrl.ToLower().Contains("test") && Request.Form["orderPage_environment"].ToLower().Contains("test"))
            {
                lblError.Text = "Unable to verify credit card. Request is in test mode, but the site is not.  Contact Customer Service.";
            }

            Response.Write("<span class='ccInfo hide'>");
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Count; i++)
            {
                var key = Request.Form.GetKey(i);

                if (key != "__VIEWSTATE")
                {
                    Response.Write("<input type='hidden' id='" + key + "' name='" + key + "' value='" + Request.Form[i] + "' class='hide' />");
                }
            }
            Response.Write("</span>");

            if (decision != "ACCEPT")
            {
                string reasonCode = Request.Form["reasonCode"];

                lblError.Text = "Unable to verify credit card (" + reasonCode + ") ";
                if (reasonCode == "102")
                {
                    lblError.Text += "<br />One or more fields in the request contains invalid data.  Typically this is the expiration date";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Unable to verify credit card. Transaction Signature not valid.  Contact Customer Service.";
        }
    }
}
```

The JavaScript we use to get that data to then send to the parent page is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var decision = $('#decision');

    if (decision.length > 0) {
        if (decision.val() === "ACCEPT") {
            //pass in requestId, etc to the billing page
            parent.$('.checkoutform').append($('.ccInfo').children());

            //call billing.aspx submit function
            parent.submitBillingPage();

            return;
        } else {
            //change from loading animation to iframe
            parent.toggleIframe(true);
        }
    }
});
```

The parent page has "checkoutform" class name so we can append all of the elements of the ccInfo span in our iframe.  This one liner shoves all of the elements we wrote out using our server side code to the parent page.  Now the parent page has all of the information that came back from CyberSource.

Our billing page (the parent page) allows for other payments besides the CyberSource credit card, so we basically do a submit on the main page assuming everything came back from CyberSource successfully.  We display the main submit button on the billing page when the user isn't paying with CyberSource.  If they are, we hide the main submit button and the submit button in the iframe is displayed instead.  We then either display error messages in the iframe if something went wrong or we do form submit on the parent page after transferring the data from the iframe to the parent page.

Finally, the parent page has access to all of the data through server side code by looking at the Request.Form.

Hopefully this helps or at least gets you going in the right direction.  I know this question is over a month old and you may have moved on, but maybe it will help someone else down the line.